# I want to send my form data to an api in angular9 .I have written api using asp.net

Tags: c#, html, angular, forms, api

I want to send my form data to web api when user clicks the submit button.I saw some demos and I tried this code.I just know basics.someone help me to do this and also If possible please say how to do get and delete methods too and also i have omitted the observables concept because Im not familiar with it. The final doubt is where to subscribe whether in component.ts or service file.? Please give your answers in layman term , Thank you so much in advance.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9ev32y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpost-method.service.ts

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject `httpClient` and then you can simpy call:

```
this.httpClient.get<_TYPE_>('_URL_')
```

Same for delete:

```
this.httpClient.delete('_URL_')
```

Comment: ok, can u solve the problem in my code in stackblitz???. I'm unable to post my data please help me with that.Thanks for your answer

Comment: im not sure if this is what you want, but you have to assign it to a property and then you bind this property to your html because you wont know when or even if you get a result from the api. here is your example edited: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5xftn3?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Yannick i tried ur code but still the data is not posted to web api.

Comment: did you check your url? or could you show me the errors you get? and could show me your api endpoint?

Comment: I did not get any errors.when i send data using postman im able to see the data in table.